# Use backward reference in match operator in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I can use backward reference in `-Replace` operator in PowerShell. For example, this code

```
'abc456' -Replace '(abc)\d*', '$1def'
```

returns `abcdef`. But I would like to use it not only with `-Replace` operator but also with `-Match` to check whether some string satisfies a regular expression. 
Something like this

```
'aa' -Match '[a]$1'
```

But the code above returns false. Is it possible to use backward reference with `-Match` operator?

Comment: `'aa' -Match '(a)\1'`?

Comment: `\1` is not a backword reference, it is an inline backreference, and it is supported by .NET regex. Actually, all these basic constructs are already dealt with [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you write an answer below I will accept it

Comment: `'aa' -Match '(?<char>a)\k<char>'` would be the named alternative.  See [Backreference Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions).